# How to handle Attachments.Add errors while preparing an email through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the [code from Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) to prepare a mail report in Outlook from an Excel file.

I modified slightly the code in order to include a table from the Excel file, text around and, potentially, an attachment. I have problem with this attachment.

To handle the possibility of an attachment, I added to Ron de Bruin code this line with mAtt being a string containing the location of the file to attach:

```
If mAtt <> vbNullString Then .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
```

While it handles properly any call to the subroutine with mAtt argument equal to "" (in such case I want to prepare the mail WITHOUT attachment), I don’t get any result when a string is provided but the file cannot be found (unreachable file servers or non existent file). The mail object is simply not displayed.

With error handling, nothing happen (whereas I see, by the time of execution or by executing step-by-step, that the code is properly doing the RangeToHtml part of the procedure). Without error handling, it just stops at the above line as it could be expected.

**I would like my code to go on in case of attachment problem and still display an Outlook mail ready to be sent, despite lacking attachment.**

Is there any better way to manage Attachments.Add VBA function?

Here is my full code.

```
Sub PrepareOutlookMail(mTo As String, mCC As String, mSub As String, mAtt As String, mTab As Range, Optional mailBegin As String, Optional mailEnd As String)
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    If mTab Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = mTO
        .CC = mCC
        .Subject = mSub
        If mAtt <> vbNullString Then .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
        .HTMLBody = mailBegin & RangetoHTML(mTab) & mailEnd
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

ADD: I also tried to add a condition to test the existence of the file as advised on some other answers about VBA.

```
If mAtt <> vbNullString And Len(Dir(mAtt,vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
```

Yet, it does not change the behaviour: nothing is displayed. When I activate errors, I face the *Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number*.

Comment: You don't get any error because `On Error Resume Next` is hiding it. You could use `Dir` to test if the file actually exists before attempting to attach it.

Comment: To be complete, when I withdraw ~~~On Error Resume Next~~~, I bumped into a run-time error (80070035) with the message "The operation failed". I am testing it here now without access to the folder of the attachment. Hence, I know that it will fail in all case.

Comment: If the vbNullString test fails then the Dir() still runs - you need to separate those into two distinct tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
If mAtt <> vbNullString And Len(Dir(mAtt,vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
```

Even if the vbNullString test above fails, the Dir() test still runs - you need to separate those into two distinct tests:

```
If Len(mAtt) > 0 Then
    If Len(Dir(mAtt,vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then 
        .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
    End If
End If
```

Edit: if you receive paths which you might not have access to, then something like this should work

```
Dim f
If Len(mAtt) > 0 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    f = Dir(mAtt)
    On Error Goto 0
    'Len(f) will be 0 if file does not exist or is unreachable
    If Len(f) <> 0 Then .Attachments.Add mAtt,0
End If
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yet, this does not address my problem. In my case (trying to attach to a mail a file located in a unreachable folder), the string mAtt (the location of the file) was properly defined and the test return TRUE. In the case where this test would return FALSE (in such case, no file location has been provided), then the second test would also fail.

Comment: I missed that your main issue was paths you didn't have access to, not paths which did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get through my problem, while I do not understand exactly why the solution works.

I simply added a SECOND error handling around the attachment problem, in a GoTo format and it now works (an Outlook email appears, without the attachment of course, instead of nothing before).

I do not understand why it works differently as it behaves exactly like the initial Resume Next error handling normally. Yet, it solves the problem.

```
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = mTo
        .cc = mCC
        .subject = mSub
        On Error GoTo hello: 'New error handling added to my initial code
        If mAtt <> vbNullString And Dir(mAtt) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add mAtt Else Resume Next
hello: 'The new error handling behaves de facto like a Resume Next...
        .HTMLBody = mailBegin & RangetoHTML(mTab) & mailEnd
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
```